# Why does this simple inverse-finding-transformation work conceptually?

Tags: matrices, inverse

In my first year at Uni I learned that one could find the inverse of a matrix, $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$, by solving an equation/system such as

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & 1 & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$

into

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0 & b_{11} & b_{12} \\
0 & 1 & b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{array}
$$

where $B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{bmatrix} = A^{-1}$.

After learning that matrices are essentially linear transformations stretching other matrices/vectors by a certain factor, the determinant. I now wonder how this simple transformation makes sense.

If usually a matrix $A_{n\times m}$ can transform a matrix $B_{m \times q}$ into $C_{n \times q}$ and the inverse doing the inverse, from $n\times q$ to $n\times m$ I wonder how this simple transformation can simply do that. Seems like magic to me.

(Remark: In case I violated some rules on questions, just let me know, I'll try to fix it right away.)

Answer (score 1):

Row operations can be represented by [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,when%20R%20is%20a%20field.) reducing elimination to matrix multiplication. If I have an invertible matrix $A$ I can decompose it into a collection of elementary matrices $A=E_1E_2...E_n$ which you can think of as starting with the identity matrix then doing row operations to produce $A$. Now if we're interested in some $B$ so that $AB=I$ with $I$ the identity matrix I can multiply on the left by the inverses of the elementary matrices in reverse order because $(E_1E_2...E_n)^{-1}=E_n^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}...E_1^{-1}$ and this justifies the algorithm you've described.